# Is Windows Machine GUID no longer a valid UUID?

Tags: windows, microsoft, uuid, windows-11, guid

I deal with a lot of Windows devices and I have yet to see one with a Machine GUID that is not a valid UUID until now. I have seen 2 devices like this.

I run the command
`Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography -Name "MachineGuid"` and receive what looks like a valid UUID4 in the 8-4-4-4-12 format with a 4 at the beginning of the 3rd group until the very end where there is a capital "T". The T is not valid hexadecimal and is capitalized while the rest of the letters are lowercase. The T is in the 32nd position of what would otherwise have been a valid UUID.

`xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxT`
They are both physical machines running Windows 11. What does the T mean? What convention is Microsoft using here if it is not UUID anymore for machine GUID? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but this is definitely not true on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm just speculating but perhaps it is Microsoft's way of indicating "trial" (T for trial) if the windows 11 install is in the 90 day enterprise trial/unactivated.

Comment: I just tested this on a VM by doing a fresh install of Windows 11 Pro with *no* activation. There is no `T`; just a standard UUID ending in `b`.